# Update the Date Part of DateTime Fields to Lastday-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I am using SQL Server 2005.

In one of my stored procedure, I have a parameter called `@pstatDate` of type `DateTime`.

I have to simple update the datePart of the Parameter to Lastday of that month.

For example if the date is `Apr 23 2012  2:15PM` I need it update it to `Apr 30 2012  2:15PM`

How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
DECLARE @Today DATETIME
SET @Today=GETDATE()

SELECT DATEADD(DAY,-DAY(DATEADD(MONTH,MONTH(@Today)+1,@Today)),
DATEADD(MONTH,1,@Today))
```

You could also do it like this:

```
SELECT @Today+datediff(day, @Today, dateadd(month, 1, @Today))-
DATEPART(day,@Today)
```

Like @Aaron Bertrand said:

> I'd be careful about using implicit date math (@Today+...) because
>   this syntax will fail on newer data types (the OP may eventually move
>   off SQL Server 2005 and be enticed by DATE or DATETIME2, or other
>   readers may already be using DATE etc.)

So according to that then something like this:

```
SELECT DATEADD(DD,datediff(day, @Today, dateadd(month, 1, @Today))-
DATEPART(day,@Today),@Today)
```

Comment: +1 but please spell out the datepart arguments (e.g. `MONTH` instead of `m`). Not all of the lazy shorthand formats are intuitive and it is much better for your code to be self-documenting than terse. IMHO.

Comment: returns `2012-01-31 15:37:00.200` instead of `2012-04-31 15:37:00.200`

Comment: @Arion: Does not work in SQL-Server 2005(as requested) since you cannot declare and initialize a variable in one step. Anyway +1

Comment: @TimSchmelter : Sorry about that. I hate Mondays. I updated the answer according to your points:)

Comment: I'd be careful about using implicit date math (`@Today+...`) because this syntax will fail on newer data types (the OP may eventually move off SQL Server 2005 and be enticed by DATE or DATETIME2, or other readers may already be using DATE etc.)

Comment: @AaronBertrand : I will add that to the answer. So you suggest a dateadd instead? right?

Comment: Yes, an explicit DATEADD is more verbose but more future-proof.

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @pstatDate DATETIME;
SET @pstatDate = 'Apr 23 2012 2:15PM';

SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, 1, DATEADD(DAY, 0-DAY(@pstatDate), @pstatDate));
```

Result:

```
-----------------------
2003-04-30 14:15:00.000
```

Comment: Sorry I originally read sentences 1, 2 and 4 in the original question.

Comment: Does not work in SQL-Server 2005(as requested) since you cannot declare and initialize a variable in one step. Anyway +1

Comment: Ok thanks Tim, corrected. I think that declaration was irrelevant because the OP already has a declared and initialized variable.